# How to elimitate ssh login delay

Tags: server, 18.04, remote-login

i have a small (4 seconds) login delay on my 18.04 ubuntu servers, that drives me crazy:

```
$ time ssh root@gateway exit

real    0m4,066s
user    0m0,015s
sys     0m0,005s
```

I've already checked the "usual" culprits: DNS, Avahi, pam_systemd.so, they aren't the cause. I've also shorten out /etc/profile, /etc/bash.bashrc, /root/.bashrc by putting a "exit 0" in the beginning of these files. It causes a little faster connect of 0m3,915s. So, they aren't the cause, either.

The `ssh -vvv` shows, the whole time is lost after:

```
...
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug3: send packet: type 90
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug3: send packet: type 80
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
```

So, it seems not a problem with ssh itself. I'am guessing, there are running additional scripts on login that are stealing my time, but which are they and where they get triggerd?

Comment: When you login via ssh then all executables in `/etc/update-motd.d/` are run to show "the message of the day" and whatnot. Maybe one of them is the culprit?

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for the hint with `/etc/update-motd.d/`, i've quashed most of these buggers there one by one. Problem is solved.

Hall of shame:

```
50-landscape-sysinfo -> 2,6sec loss
80-esm -> 0,5sec loss
95-hwe-eol -> 0,5sec loss
```

Comment: You are still missing 1.4sec from your original 4 ;-)

Comment: 4 - (2,6 + 0,5 + 0,5) = 0,4
Thats ok.

Comment: @AlexanderGaengel how did you measure this??

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem, but the existing solutions didn't solve it. The timing was even worse:

```
user@my_machine ~
$ time ssh my_server exit

real    0m25.724s
user    0m0.031s
sys     0m0.062s

user@my_machine ~
$ time ssh my_server exit

real    0m25.444s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.077s
```

To debug what was taking so long, I increased the ssh verbosity via the `-vvv` option as in

```
time ssh -vvv my_server exit
```

...which made it obvious that the time was taken during the `pledge: network` stage, which allowed me to search for that specific problem.

What helped in the end was to

- set `UsePAM` to `no` in */etc/ssh/sshd_config* as [suggested on ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/a/792494/123289),
- followed by `sudo service sshd restart`.

According to [this post on ubuntuforums](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1749340&p=10768716#post10768716), disabling PAM should be fine when using keys:

> If you are using keys you should disable password authentication
>   (PAM).
>
> This will increase security.

Answer (score 0):

I once had a similar problem. It turned out that it was a printer that had a fault and was blasting the network with job requests or something. Replaced the printer and most of the network problems evaporated.